# Population Projection, Forecast, Prediction

Tags: self-study, references, terminology, demography

I am frequently reading some terminology But not understanding their difference .

Those are :

#### $\bullet$Difference between `Population Projection and Population Forecast`

#### $\bullet$Difference between `Population Projection and Prediction`

#### $\bullet$Difference between `Population Forecast and Prediction`

Comment: Can you give some context? Where are you reading these things? Are you sure the differences in terminology are being used to distinguish different concepts?

Comment: @Scortchi yes, I am quite sure, the demographers use those terminology to distinguish different aspects. I downloaded a pdf  from internet where they have just mentioned that there is difference but not explained what is the difference. Also The book `The Methods And Materials of Demography`  by `Siegel & Swanson` gave the difference of `projection and forecast` but it is not clear to me.I wish of an example(could be mathematical example of artificial data).

Comment: So it's predictions/forecasts/projections *of* population *size*, rather than predictions/forecasts/projections *for* a population *from* a sample?

Answer (score 2):

A *prediction* is most general—of new observations from a model based on old ones. The "new" observations needn't be temporally subsequent to the old ones—you could predict population sizes of a dinosaur species from a model based on extant fauna.

You can call a prediction a *forecast* when the new observations are a continuation in time of a series of prior observations.

If you call a forecast a *projection*, you're stressing its hypotheticality—like those calculations showing that if current population growth rates continue we'll all be standing on each other's shoulders in so many years' time.

NB Siegel & Swanson put it a bit differently, describing *the* forecast as the one of several projections you choose to hang your hat on.